# CakePHP 3 can't generate correct URL when using admin routing

Tags: php, cakephp

Building a basic CMS in CakePHP 3.7.3 based on the tutorial: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/installation.html

I have 3 Controllers:

- `Controller/Admin/ArticlesController.php`
- `Controller/Admin/UsersController.php`
- `Controller/ArticlesController.php`

I have also configured my routes (`config/routes.php`) as follows:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    // All routes here will be prefixed with `/admin`
    // And have the prefix => admin route element added.
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});

$routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'home']);

$routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
```

To access the CMS a user has to login which they do via `/admin/users/login`. This works as expected using Cake's Auth feature.

The logged in user accesses the `index()` function of `Admin/ArticlesController.php` which displays a list of records in the `articles` table. This works correctly. However I am trying to generate a URL to view the article on the frontend.

I have used the HTML Helper to create the URL like this inside `Template/Admin/Articles/index.ctp`:

```
$this->Html->link($article->title, ['action' => 'view', $article->slug])
```

This produces a URL:

```
/admin/articles/view/foo
```

The Controller responsible for the viewing articles on the public (non-Admin) frontend is `Controller/ArticlesController.php` (note this is *NOT* within the `Admin/` sub-directory). I tried adapting the code above to:

```
$this->Html->link($article->title, ['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'view', $article->slug])
```

This still produces the wrong URL. The URL should be `/articles/view/foo` (where "foo" is the `articles.slug` field).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `prefix` key is persistent by default, just like the `plugin`, `controller` and `action` keys, ie just like you can omit  the `controller` key in your example, you can omit the `prefix` key, and the router will pick it up automatically from the current request parameters.

You have to explicitly override the `prefix` key if you want to break out of its context:

```
['prefix' => false, 'controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'view', $article->slug]
```

Note that unlike for the `plugin` key, you cannot use `null` to unset it, you must use `false`!

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Creating Links to Plugin Routes](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-links-to-plugin-routes)**